# Placing total counts above stacked bars of barplot where stacked bars are already labeled with percentages

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

This is my data frame:

```
no_q1 <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
           count = c(47L, 36L, 51L, 44L, 34L, 38L, 44L, 33L, 22L, 27L, 16L,    
                     17L, 13L, 2L, 7L, 11L, 10L, 13L, 8L, 3L),
           prop = c(0.661971830985915, 0.553846153846154,
                0.671052631578947, 0.619718309859155,
                0.62962962962963, 0.575757575757576, 0.745762711864407,
                0.464788732394366, 0.338461538461538, 0.355263157894737,
                0.225352112676056, 0.314814814814815, 0.196969696969697,
                0.0338983050847458, 0.0985915492957746, 0.169230769230769,
                0.131578947368421, 0.183098591549296,
                0.148148148148148, 0.0454545454545455),
       sum = c("71", "65", "76", "71", "54", "66", "59", "71", "65",
               "76", "71", "54", "66", "59", "71", "65", "76",
               "71", "54", "66"),
       Participant = as.factor(c("q5", "q5", "q5", "q5", "q5", "q5", "q5",
                                 "q6", "q6", "q6", "q6", "q6", "q6", "q6",
                                 "q8", "q8", "q8", "q8", "q8", "q8")),
       Month = as.factor(c("Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep",
                           "Oct", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug",
                           "Sep", "Oct", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul",
                           "Aug", "Sep"))
)
```

and this is my plot:

```
ggplot(no_q1, aes(x = Month, y = prop, fill = Participant)) +
  geom_bar(position = "stack", stat = "identity") +
  geom_text(position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5), aes(label = 
paste0(round(no_q1$prop*100, 2), "%"))) +
  geom_text(aes(label = sum, y = 1.3))
```

My question is how can I make the counts appear exactly above the bars. Currently they all have the same height but I want them to be exactly above each bar. Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Unfortunately, the answer in the link does not work for this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)

# dataset to use to plot the sum number above stacked bars
d2 = no_q1 %>% group_by(Month, sum) %>% summarise(prop = sum(prop))

ggplot() +
  geom_bar(data=no_q1, aes(x = Month, y = prop, fill = Participant), position = "stack", stat = "identity") +
  geom_text(data=no_q1, position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5), aes(x = Month, y = prop, group = Participant, label = paste0(round(no_q1$prop*100, 2), "%"))) +
  geom_text(data=d2, aes(x = Month, y = prop, label=sum),vjust=0)
```

[image]